# Error con la ruta de un UPDATE en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rutas, update, error404

disculpen vengo buscando ayuda con un problema, en un sistema estoy desarrollando un módulo para registrar un grupo de trabajadores de una empresa de construcción, pero tengo problemas con las rutas, el método store lo desarrollé bien y es capaz de insertar campos nuevos, pero al momento de trabajar con el update, tengo problemas con las rutas, según yo todo está bien, pero me da un error 404 al intentar actualizar una serie de campos, abajo comparto capturas de cómo he trabajado con esto, y de antemano agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda que pudiesen brindarme.

Este es el método update en el controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista donde se está ejecutando el update:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que se ejecuta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo con las rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento actualizar el registro me da este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en consola me dice que no encuentra la ruta, pero todo parece estar en orden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que la ruta se espera como parámetro el `Id` del modelo a actualizar y tu le estás pasando literalmente 'test'.

```php-template
route('maestroObras.update',{Id})
```

| Verb | URI | Action | Route Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PUT/PATCH | /photos/{photo} | update | photos.update |

> [Laravel Controllers - Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)